# C# Structs: Mutability versus Performance

Tags: c#, performance, struct

I realize that structs are meant to be immutable, that mutating structs is evil, and the proper way to change values in a struct is by creating new instances. However, I am not clear on the memory and performance aspects/issues of new instances versus allowing the struct to be mutable.

Suppose I have the struct,

```
struct Vehicle
{
    public readonly int Number;
    public readonly double Speed, Direction;

    public Vehicle(int number, double speed, double direction)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Speed = speed;
        this.Direction = direction;
    }
}
```

And  create it as:

```
Vehicle car;
```

as well as

```
Vehicle plane = new Vehicle(1234, 145.70, 73.20)
```

If I need to assign to Number, Speed, or Direction later, I could remove the readonly and make the struct mutable - I know it is eveil to do this. - thereby "mutating" an already created struct value.

Alternatively I could create a new struct instance. So instead of saying car.Speed = 120.7; I could say car = new Vehicle(car.Number, 178.55, car.Direction);. That would create a new struct value almost like the old value, only with the Speed changed. But it wouldn't mutate the existing struct value.

Here is the issue. Suppose, as an extreme example, I need to update the speed and/or the direction many, many thousands of times per second. I would think that the creation of this many instances would severely impact memory and performance, and that in this case it would be better to allow the struct to be mutable.

Can anyone please clarify the memory and performance issues of a mutable struct versus the proper way to implement a struct in this type of an extreme case?

Comment: A `Vehicle` probably shouldn't be a struct in the first place. With the proper choices this whole issue doesn't come up.

Comment: If it needs to represent something with state, you should be using a `class` instead.

Comment: Youa re correct that vehicle is probably not the right thing but the questioin is still valid. The question is performance and memory of mutable struct versus creating many instances. I a not sure how a class would help with state.

Comment: "Performance" and "memory [usage]" issues cannot be answered so generally. Without a proper context this question is meaningless.

Comment: Immutability enlarges your optimization scenarios, embracing safe threading, pooling and caching, which is hard to achieve using mutable objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two distinct usage cases for structs; in some cases, one wants a type that encapsulates a single value and behaves mostly like a class, but with better performance and a non-null default value.  In such cases, one should use what I would call an opaque structure; MSDN's guidelines for structures are written on the assumption that this is the only usage case.

In other cases, however, the purpose of the struct is simply to bind some variables together with duct tape.  In those cases, one should use a transparent struct which simply exposes those variables as public fields.  There is nothing evil about such types.  What's evil is the notion that everything should behave like a class object, or that everything should be "encapsulated".  If the semantics of the struct are such that:

1. There is some fixed set of readable members (fields or properties) which expose its entire state

   Given any set of desired values for those members, one can create an instance with those values (no combinations of values are forbidden).

   The default value of the struct should be to have all those members set to the default values of their respective types.

and any change to them would break the code which uses it, then there is nothing which future versions of the struct could possibly do which a transparent struct would not be able to do, nor is there anything that a transparent struct would allow which a future version of the struct would be able to prevent.  Consequently, encapsulation imposes cost without adding value.

I would suggest that one should endeavor to, whenever practical, make all structs either transparent or opaque.  Further, I would suggest that because of deficiencies in the way .net handles struct methods, one should avoid having opaque structures' public members modify `this` except perhaps in property setters.  It is ironic that while MSDN's guidelines suggest one shouldn't use a struct for things that don't represent a "single value", in the common scenario where one simply wants to pass a group of variables from one piece of code to another, transparent structs are vastly superior to opaque structs or class types, and the margin of superiority *grows* with the number of fields.

BTW, with regard to the original question, I would suggest that it's useful to represent that your program may want to deal with two kinds of things: (1) a car, and (2) information related to a particular car.  I would suggest that it may be helpful to have a struct `CarState`, and have instances of `Car` hold a field of type `CarState`.  This would allow instances of `Car` to expose their state to outside code and possibly allow outside code to modify their state under controlled circumstances (using methods like

```
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2);
delegate void ActionByRef<T1,T2,T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 p2, T3 p3);

void UpdateState<TP1>(ActionByRef<CarState, TP1> proc, ref TP1 p1)
{ proc(ref myState, ref p1); }
void UpdateState<TP1,TP2>(ActionByRef<CarState, TP1,TP2> proc, ref TP1 p1, ref TP2 p2)
{ proc(ref myState, ref p1, ref p2); }
```

Note that such methods offer most of the performance advantages of having the car's state be a mutable class, but without the dangers associated with promiscuous object references.  A `Car` can let outside code may update a car's state via the above methods without allowing outside code to modify its state at any other time.

BTW, I really wish .net had a way of specifying that a "safe" struct or class should be considered as encapsulating the members of one or more of its constituents [e.g. so that struct which held a `Rectangle` called `R` and an `String` called `Name` could be regarded as having a fields `X`, `Y`, `Width`, and `Height` which alias the corresponding struct fields.  If that were possible, it would greatly facilitate situations where a type needs to hold more state than previously expected.  I don't think the present CIL allows for such aliasing in a safe type, but there's no conceptual reason it couldn't.

Answer (score 3):

The question you need to answer for yourself is "what are the intended semantics of the type I'm writing?"

A `struct` should be used instead of a `class` when you're trying to write a [value type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type). A good example of a value type is `DateTime`. Regardless of anything else that's going on, January 12th, 2013 at 3:33PM GMT-7 is always going to be January 12th, 2013 at 3:33PM GMT-7. A color is another good example; two colors made up of RGB 255, 0, 0 are never going to be different in any way.

The type you're trying to create, `Vehicle`, does not have [value semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics) as you want it to contain state that is meant to be updated for a specific instance of a car. Therefore, you should be writing a mutable `class` instead of a `struct`.

Comment: Fair and valid point. OK then if I have a mutable class and I am creating thousands and thousands of instnce os it, then what are the memory and performance implications?

Comment: It sounds like you're about to fall prey to premature optimization. My advice: write the program the way you think it should be written, and then decide whether or not the performance is acceptable. If it's not, then you can look into further optimization.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but I need to consider this. Writing the code and then having to modify it after the fact to deal with memory/performance issues is not a reasonable oprion if I can elimante it with proper understanding of the memory/performance aspects of what I am proposing to do.

Comment: Then you need to do a small proof-of-concept performance comparison before you begin actual development. The only way to get meaningful results when looking at performance issues like this is to *try it yourself*.

Comment: The `DateTime` is a good analogy. You are not allowed to say `myDateTime.Day = 1;` because it's immutable. You **could** say `myDateTime = new DateTime(myDateTime.Year, myDateTime.Month, 1);`. But there's also a lot of helpful instance methods to create the new `DateTime` value, so you could say e.g. `myDateTime = myDateTime.AddDays(1 - myDateTime.Day);`. (I know these two are not equivalent when the original `DateTime` has a time-of-day component.) In the same way, an immutable `Vehicle` struct could have a `ChangeSpeed` method that created a **new** object where only the speed is changed.

Comment: Thank you for the asnswer but this is getting away from the original question. The original question was the memory and performance impact of mutable struct versus creating new instances. Simalry what about new instances of mutable class?

Comment: @PBrenek: Mutable classes are good for representing entities, decent for holding unshared values, and bad for holding values that will need to be shared.  Structures are generally bad for representing entities and good for holding values whether shared or not.

Comment: Things like `DateTime` demonstrate an excellent usage case for opaque structures, but hardly the only usage case for structures.  Things like `Rectangle` and `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` represent a usage case for what should be (but alas aren't) transparent structures, whose state is nothing more nor less than the set of values stored in public fields.  In cases where one needs to pass around a group of discrete values bound together with duct tape, transparent structs are a perfect fit.  One could use immutable class object (and in some cases one may have no choice), or...

Comment: ...one could use an opaque struct which pretends to be an immutable class object, but in many situations such "encapsulation" will add overhead without adding any value.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll only answer the performance aspect of this question. I'll spare you the premature optimization warning and the discussion about semantics.*

Yes, assigning the whole struct has a performance cost. It introduces assignments which were not present in the mutating variant. I do not trust the JIT to optimize them out as the .NET JIT is pretty simple (it is optimized for fast code-gen).

Probably, these assignments are very cheap because they are contiguous in memory and the memory cache line has been loaded already. No memory transaction needs to occur because of them.

The performance difference will be small (for reasonably sized structs). You will be able to measure it, though.

It also introduces clutter into your code to create a new instance of the struct for each mutation. I have encountered cases in practice where I found it to be best to use mutable structs from a code quality perspective. Those are just a few cases but they exist.

Comment: This is what I am thinking as well. I also do not like to rely on the JIT for optimizations. I too think that in special cases mutable structs are far cleaner than creating instances and also have better performance.  What about classes in the same situation?

Comment: With classes you pay a hefty penalty for new instances. Allocation is cheap but the GC is not. Fortunately, you don't run into problems with mutability.; So there is a trade-off that you have to make.

Comment: Ah, you're actually advocating evil, in "few" cases. Great, why fear evil? More seriously, regarding the "clutter" in the code you mention: Your immutable struct could have an instance method `ChangeSpeedField(double newSpeed)` that returned the new struct value where only the `Speed` was changed.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen good suggestion. One could consider the mutator methods clutter, though. And it gets nasty when you want to assign multiple fields. Workable for sure, but not perfect.

Comment: True, but if say the speed is being updated 1000 times per second then we still have the memory/performance issue of many, many instances, don't we?

Comment: @PBrenek yes absolutely. There is a place for mutable structs. Sometimes they are valid design choices.

Comment: So it would appear that in cases where you need to do many mutations mutable structs are a valid option. So if I am focusing on capturing rapidly changing state data which gets finalized (no longer mutated) after say 1 sec and then stays the same, would I be better of with a mutable struct or a class?

Comment: If you don't mind the per-object overhead of a class then by all means go with a mutable class. IF you prefer structs I recommend that you do a simple benchmark to find out if you care about the small difference in perf.

Comment: @usr: Mutable class objects are okay for holding data, but not good for passing it around, since there's no nice way for an object which stores values in a mutable class object to expose those values to outside code without either exposing the object in which they are stored (bad) or manually copying the values to something else (i.e. not using the mutable object for data interchange).  Mutable structures can work well for both purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. That was my feeling as well and that's why I opted to use a struct rather than a class. Butt hen I ran into the mutability issue versus memory/performance implication of creating new instance of the same struct with different field values.